R で lubridate の日付計算に条件をつけたい
開始日（Startdate）、終了日１（Finishdate1)、終了日２（Finishdate2）という3つの日付変数があるデータセットがあり、開始日には欠損値はありませんが、終了日１と２にはそれぞれ複数欠損値があります。
開始日と終了日１の間の日数（daystoevent)をこちらで計算しました。
test$daystoevent<-difftime(test$Finishdate1, test$Startdate)

その次に、終了日１がmissingだった場合にFinishdate2を用いて、開始日と終了日２の日数を計算し、daystoeventに入れたいのですが、どのように条件式を作ればよいのでしょうか。
宜しくお願いいたします。

欠損値の判定には is.na() 関数が使えます。
lubridate が使われていることから，それを含む tidyverse を用いた記述例を下記に示します。
library(tidyverse)

Startdate <- ymd(c(240101, 240201, 240301, 240401, 240501, 240601))
Finishdate1 <- ymd(c(240111, NA, 240311, 240411, NA, NA))
Finishdate2 <- ymd(c(240121, 240221, NA, 240421, NA, 240621))

test <- tibble(Startdate, Finishdate1, Finishdate2) |>
    mutate(daystoevent = if_else(is.na(Finishdate1),
                                 difftime(Finishdate2, Startdate),
                                 difftime(Finishdate1, Startdate)))
test
## # A tibble: 6 × 4
##   Startdate  Finishdate1 Finishdate2 daystoevent
##   <date>     <date>      <date>      <drtn>
## 1 2024-01-01 2024-01-11  2024-01-21  10 days
## 2 2024-02-01 NA          2024-02-21  20 days
## 3 2024-03-01 2024-03-11  NA          10 days
## 4 2024-04-01 2024-04-11  2024-04-21  10 days
## 5 2024-05-01 NA          NA          NA days
## 6 2024-06-01 NA          2024-06-21  20 days


本質的なことではありませんが、念のためコメントします。
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
もし、回答のコードを実行し、関数が見つからない系のエラーが出る場合は、冒頭にこの二つもつけるとよいと思います。
library(tibble)には、tibbleが入っていて、
library(dplyr)には、mutate、if_elseが入っています。
